# Populating stack causes error

Tags: java

I'm populating a stack instance variable with elements of the array `el`, but in the line below it's giving me an error although I specified that it's a stack of Integers.

#### Error:

> Incompatible types - found java.util.Stack but expected java.lang.Integer...

#### Code:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class SortedStack
{
  private Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

  public SortedStack(Integer[] el)
  {
      for(int i = 0; i < el.length; i++)
      {
          el[i] = stack;  /** THIS LINE*/
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: and whats the error? specifying that in your post will always get more answers

Comment: Why is this marked as community wiki?

Comment: It's because there's a lot of edits by various users to this post, probably because of its bad formatting, poor English and so on, and thus once too many users contribute to this post, it becomes CW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an item to the top of the stack, use the push method.

Example:

```
  public SortedStack(Integer[] el)
  {
      for(int i = 0; i < el.length; i++)
      {
          stack.push(el[i]);
      }
  }
```

This will push elements from the `el` array into the stack.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add elements of el into stack . You were trying to assign stack object to el[i] which is not possible. Its obvious that you got error.

So your code should be like following :

```
public class SortedStack 
{ 
  private Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>(); 

  public SortedStack(Integer[] el) 
  { 
      for(int i = 0; i < el.length; i++) 
      { 
          stack.push(el[i];
      } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java developer but I'm guessing if you want to put a value on the stack you'll need something like:

```
stack.push(el[i]);
```

The reason for your error is your trying to assign the i-th Element in an Integer array, to be a Stack. This is failing because it can't cast a Stack to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Stack.push()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#push%28E%29) method.

```
stack.push(el[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a stack, you want to `push()` your item on top of it, and `pop()` it from the stack when you're ready to use it again. In your case, it seems more appropriate to *inherit* the stack, than to wrap it.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class SortedStack extends Stack<Integer>
{    
  public SortedStack(Integer[] el) // Why "Sorted"? You're not sorting here...
  {
      for(int i = 0; i < el.length; i++)
      {
          this.push(el[i]);  /** THE ERROR IS THIS LINE */
      }
  }
}
```

Doing this, you can use your `SortedStack` just like any regular stack, with the addition of adding a whole range of elements in the constructor. You might also want to implement a `PushRange()` method, that can be called after the object is instantiated.